# Hard coding confidence interval as whiskers in bar plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

So I calculated the confident interval for a set of data with a normal distribution and I want to plot it as whiskers on the bar chart of the data mean. I tried using yerr parameter for the plt.bar but it calculates the standard deviation error not the confident interval.I want the same whiskers visualizations on the bar plot. 
The confident intervals I have are:

[(29600.87 , 39367.28 ),
 ( 37101.74 , 42849.60 ),
 ( 33661.12 , 41470.25 ),
 ( 46019.20 , 49577.80)]

Here's my code, I tried feeding the yerr parameters with the confident levels but did't work out so well.

```
means=[np.mean(df.iloc[x]) for x in range(len(df.index))]

CI=[st.t.interval(0.95, len(df.iloc[x])-1, loc=np.mean(df.iloc[x]), scale=st.sem(df.iloc[x])) for x in range(len(df.index))]

plt.figure()

plt.bar(x_axis, means, color='r',yerr=np.reshape(CI,(2,4))

plt.xticks(np.arange(1992,1996,1))
```

Here's the plot I'm getting:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following should do what you want (assuming that your errors are symmetric; if not then you should go with @ImportanceOfBeingErnest's answer); the plot would look like this:

[image]

The code that produces it with some inline comments:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# rough estimates of your means; replace by your actual values
means = [34500, 40000, 37500, 47800]

# the confidence intervals you provided
ci = [(29600.87, 39367.28), (37101.74, 42849.60), (33661.12, 41470.25), (46019.20, 49577.80)]

# get the range of the confidence interval
y_r = [means[i] - ci[i][1] for i in range(len(ci))]
plt.bar(range(len(means)), means, yerr=y_r, alpha=0.2, align='center')
plt.xticks(range(len(means)), [str(year) for year in range(1992, 1996)])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks!! That's what I ended up doing

Answer (score 3):

The  `yerr` argument to `bar`can be used to draw the errors as errorbars. The errors are defined as the deviation from some value, i.e. often quantities are given in the form `y ± err`. This means the the confidence interval would be `(y-err, y+err)`.
This can be inverted; given a confidence interval `(a, b)` and a value `y`, the errors would be `y-a` and `b-y`.

In a matplotlib bar plot the error format can be `scalar | N, Nx1 or 2xN array-like`. Since we cannot know beforehands if the `y` value lies symmetric in the interval and since it can be different for different realizations (bars), we need to choose the `2 x N`-format here.

The code below shows how to do that.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# given some mean values and their confidence intervals,
means = np.array([30, 100, 60, 80])
conf  = np.array([[24, 35],[90, 110], [52, 67], [71, 88]])

# calculate the error
yerr = np.c_[means-conf[:,0],conf[:,1]-means ].T
print (yerr) # prints [[ 6 10  8  9]
             #         [ 5 10  7  8]]

# and plot it on a bar chart
plt.bar(range(len(means)), means, yerr=yerr)
plt.xticks(range(len(means)))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: As usual, if someone downvotes, they should explain the reasons, such that the answer can be improved.

Comment: Seems fine to me. I upvoted it, first because it answers the question and second it is more general than what I posted. I assume symmetrical errors, then it becomes a bit simpler...

Comment: Thanks! I modified the error to be symmetric as Cleb pointed out.